# Generate random password in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a following function to generate random passwords:

```
function GeneratePassword(ALength: Integer; Mode: TPasswordMode): string;
const
  cLower   = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  cUpper   = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  cNumbers = '0123456789';
  cExtra   = '_.';
var
  i : Integer;
  S : string;
  iM: BYTE;
begin
  if Mode = [] then Exit;
  i := 0;
  Randomize;
  while (i < ALength)  do
  begin
    iM := RANDOM(4);
    case iM of
      0: if (pmLower in Mode) then begin
            S := S + cLower[1+RANDOM(Length(cLower))];
           Inc(i);
          end;
     1: if (pmUpper in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cUpper[1+RANDOM(Length(cUpper))];
          Inc(i);
         end;
      2: if (pmNumbers in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cNumbers[1+RANDOM(Length(cNumbers))];
           Inc(i);
          end;
      3: if (pmExtra in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cExtra[1+RANDOM(Length(cExtra))];
           Inc(i);
         end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := S;
end;
```

How to make this function so that a capital letter and a special character appear only once, but always? Sometimes there is no capital letter or special character when I'm generating passwords.

Comment: Alternatively: draw `ALength-2` common chars; draw a capital letter and insert it at a random position; draw a special char and insert it at a random position.

Comment: Alternatively: After having generated has you do now, scan the result and if there is a missing type of character (capital letter or special character), add one explicitly at a random position.

Comment: Alternatively add the required single characters first, then the rest and finally random shuffle the result.

Comment: Personally of all the ideas presented here @dsm's seems the best. Be careful to use a proper shuffle though, the subject of many a question here before.

Comment: @David insert is faster than shuffle the result.

Comment: @bosshoss are you sure? Extra heap allocations your way. But still, I'm confident that this code isn't going to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure to have one special char and one uppercase you can do that :

```
function GeneratePassword(ALength: Integer; Mode: TPasswordModes): string;
const
  cLower   = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  cUpper   = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  cNumbers = '0123456789';
  cExtra   = '_.';
var
  iM: Byte;
  i: integer;
begin
  if Mode = [] then Exit;

  Result := '';
  i := 0;

  if pmUpper in Mode then
    Inc(i);

  if pmExtra in Mode then
    Inc(i);

  // add lower case and/or number
  while Result.Length < (ALength - i)  do
  begin
    iM := Random(2);
    case iM of
      0: if (pmLower in Mode) then begin
           Result := Result + cLower[1 + Random(Length(cLower))];
         end;
      1: if (pmNumbers in Mode) then begin
           Result := Result + cNumbers[1 + Random(Length(cNumbers))];
         end;
    end;
  end;

  // add uppercase and/or extra
  if i > 0 then
  begin
    if pmUpper in Mode then
      Result := Result.Insert(1 + Random(Length(Result)), cUpper[1 + Random(Length(cUpper))]);

    if pmExtra in Mode then
      Result := Result.Insert(1 + Random(Length(Result)), cExtra[1 + Random(Length(cExtra))]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't call Randomize illike that. Once only at startup. Try calling this function twice in quick succession and see how you get the same output.

Comment: That was part of the original code. I didnt write all.

Comment: I call this function 100 times and it was ok, instead of distribut -1 and write the same comment everywhere, explain and give a better solution.

Comment: It was wrong in the code in the question too the documentation for Randomize says exactly what I said. Also, seeding for PRNGs is a pretty well known topic.

Comment: If you aren't familiar, just imagine that two consecutive calls to Randomize result in the RNG being initialised with the same seed because the internal clock hasn't changed.

Comment: To be fair recent versions of Randomize use high freq. timers rather than GetTickCount as older versions did. So, the impact of repeated calls to Randomize is a little different, and harder to describe. But thanks for removing the call. DV also removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TPasswordMode = (pmLower, pmUpper, pmNumbers, pmExtra);
  TPasswordModes = set of TPasswordMode;

implementation

function GeneratePassword(ALength: Integer; Mode: TPasswordModes): string;
const
  cLower   = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  cUpper   = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  cNumbers = '0123456789';
  cExtra   = '_.';
var
  i : Integer;
  S : string;
  iM: BYTE;
begin
  if Mode = [] then Exit;
  i := 0;
  Randomize;
  while (i < ALength)  do
  begin
    iM := RANDOM(4);
    case iM of
      0: if (pmLower in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cLower[1+RANDOM(Length(cLower))];
           Inc(i);
         end;
      1: if (pmUpper in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cUpper[1+RANDOM(Length(cUpper))];
           Inc(i);
           Mode := Mode - [pmUpper]; // This I added
         end;
      2: if (pmNumbers in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cNumbers[1+RANDOM(Length(cNumbers))];
           Inc(i);
         end;
      3: if (pmExtra in Mode) then begin
           S := S + cExtra[1+RANDOM(Length(cExtra))];
           Inc(i);
           Mode := Mode - [pmExtra];  // This I added
         end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := S;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(GeneratePassword(10,[pmLower,pmUpper,pmNumbers,pmExtra]));
end;
```

This is not a complete solution but with this you will at least remove Upper and Extra from the requirements as soon as they get taken. You now check in the end if they ever were ever added if required and then add them if so required.

---

Edit:

I was in a hurry when I typed the above. You just need to check in the end if the generated password contains an Upper and Extra character. If not, you still need to add them as that was one of your requirements.

Comment: I don't make any sense of your last sentence. I can guess what you possibly are trying to say, but please try to formulate it better.

Comment: @TomBrunberg :-). I was in a hurry when I typed the above. He just needs to check in the end if the generated password contains an Upper and Extra character. If not he still needs to add them as that was one of his requirements.

Comment: Don't call Randomize illike that. Once only at startup. Try calling this function twice in quick succession and see how you get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that first makes sure all extra modes are filled and the rest. It prefills Result with spaces and then replaces with random chars until all spaces are replaced.

```
function GetRandomEmptyPos(const aStr: string): integer; inline;
begin
  // find random empty position
  repeat
    Result := Random(Length(aStr)) + 1;
  until aStr[Result] = ' ';
end;

function GeneratePassword2(aLength: Integer; aModes: TPasswordModes): string;
const
  cLower   = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  cUpper   = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  cNumbers = '0123456789';
  cExtra   = '_.';
var
  i,vPos: integer;
  vMode: TPasswordMode;
begin
  if (aLength = 0) or (aModes = []) then Exit;
  Randomize;

  // Prefill Result with empty spaces
  Result := StringOfChar(' ', aLength);

  // Add extra characters at random places
  for vMode in aModes do
  begin
    vPos := GetRandomEmptyPos(Result);
    case vMode of
      pmLower:    Result[vPos] := cLower[Random(Length(cLower)) + 1];
      pmUpper:    Result[vPos] := cUpper[Random(Length(cUpper)) + 1];
      pmNumbers:  Result[vPos] := cNumbers[Random(Length(cNumbers)) + 1];
      pmExtra:    Result[vPos] := cExtra[Random(Length(cExtra)) + 1];
    end;
  end;

  // Add random char on emtpy spaces
  for i := 1 to Result.Length do
    if Result[i] = ' ' then
      Result[i] := String(cLower + cNumbers)[Random(Length(cLower) + Length(cNumbers)) + 1];
end;
```

Comment: He want only one extra and one upper, with your code he can get more than 1

Comment: @Bosshoss Thanks, I fixed the final adding of random chars.

Comment: Don't call Randomize illike that. Once only at startup. Try calling this function twice in quick succession and see how you get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

unrefined code but maybe it can be useful ...

```
function RandomPassword(PLen: Integer): string;
  var
    strBase: string;
    strUpper: string;
    strSpecial: string;
    strRecombine: string;
  begin
    strRecombine:='';
    Result := '';
    Randomize;
    //string with all possible chars
    strBase   := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    strUpper:='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    strSpecial:='@!_';
    // Start Random
    strRecombine:= strUpper[Random(Length(strUpper)) + 1];
    Result:=strRecombine;
    strRecombine:= strSpecial[Random(Length(strSpecial))+1];
    repeat
      Result := Result +  strBase[Random(Length(strBase)) + 1];
    until (Length(Result) = PLen);
      RandomRange(2, Length(strBase)); 
      Result[RandomRange(2, PLen)]:=strRecombine[1];
  //result:=Result+strRecombine;
end;
```